# Using height 100% inside of TD cuts content in FF

Tags: html, css

Im using following markup, but in FF (v30) td are not stretched by the last div with red backcolor.
Is it correct? It thought TD should be stretched by content (its normal behavior for td).
How I can fix it (2 divs with 100% height are necessary and can't be deleted)?

```
<table style="width: 200px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 100px;">
                    <div style="height: 100%;">
                        <div style="height: 100%; border: 2px solid green;">
                            <div style="height: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9H4R/)

Edit #1:

```
<td style="height: 100px;">
```

Height should be specified in pixels to prevent td collapsing if content is missing, so I cant use a percent values.

Answer (score 1):

remove the 100px or replace px with %

```
replace <td style="height: 100px;"> with <td style="height: 100%;">
```